# Events or Booking for Tour managment?

Tags: civievent, civibooking

I work for a NP that organizes performing arts and visual arts tours for our members.  We handle the booking, contracting etc for our members.  We are making the move to civicrm. Tours can have up to 30 dates/entries

I feel confident I will be able to move contacts over, but am starting to strategize on how to recreate or reimagine our tour management process. We do not manage the registration or selling of tickets for our members.  That is all handled locally.

Currently the flow is( This is currently in access in a tabbed form view)

Tour details(Tour name, Program, Description, image url, Agent, etc.)

> Bookings ( Presenter, Date, time, location, fee, contact person, ticket link, commission, etc)
> Artist payments ( summary of artist fees from bookings tab, payment, type, date, cheque payable to, amount)
> Evaluation (submitted dates, attendance, capacity, gross receipts, comments)

I have reviewed some videos on the Events and on the Bookings extension.  neither seem to replicate this flow.  I will likely have to either change the flow or create/alter an extension to recreate this flow.  Has anyone replicated this scenario or have any suggestion on how this may be accomplished.  I am what I would call a shade tree mechanic when it comes to php.  I can handle the basics, and edit existing code pretty well, but building from the ground up would be a challenge.

Comment: we support a client doing Tour stuff for a theatre company. we/they manage their process via Activities and (drupal) webforms. so someone makes an enquiry, that creates an activity with custom field storing all the necessary goodies. since it sounds like you are not dealing with the registrations perhaps consider this approach rather than Events or Bookings

Comment: Thanks Petednz. I've looked at that in the demo now and that does look like that might be a good option.Thansk for pointing it out!

Comment: Rookiest -glad that you are finding SE useful, but this is not an answer to the question and should be posted as a comment to the question. Please delete and repost

Comment: Thank you.  as I do not have the points required to comment I wanted to let this person know their input was valued.  is there some other mechanism for a rookie to thank some one other than answer if they are not able to comment yet?

Comment: yep it gets tricky when you start out. your reputation should increase reasonably quickly.

Comment: ok i undeleted your deleted answer. +1'ed it. converted to a comment along with the sub-comments. hopefully others (Mick??) will +1 your Q and comments to get you over the threshold. i will meanwhile add my comment as an Answer which you can then 'Accept'

Answer (score 1):

we support a client doing Tour stuff for a theatre company. we/they manage their process via Activities and (drupal) webforms. so someone makes an enquiry, that creates an activity with custom field storing all the necessary goodies. since it sounds like you are not dealing with the registrations perhaps consider this approach rather than Events or Bookings